# Why isn't Kafka ProducerListener logging trace id and span id?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a Kafka instance and a simple spring boot application with one REST controller and a `ProducerListener` bean. The controller accepts a simple `String` message and sends it to Kafka via `KafkaTemplate`. I want the `ProducerListener` to log an info message, but the trace id and span id is missing. In my opinion, it should be included in the log.

I use Spring Cloud Sleuth and Spring Kafka starters.

The message itself is successfully sent via Kafka topic to another spring boot application that gets the trace id correctly, so I assume that the problem is related just to the `ProducerListener`.

### Debugging

I have tried debugging the code and I ended up in the method `TracingProducer.send(..)`. The span instance there is `NoopSpan` (this was weird) and because of that the `TracingCallback` doesn't wrap the `Callback` and the tracing information gets lost. There are some nasty bit operations that I couldn't understand. The jar was this one `brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients-5.7.0.jar`

## The code

The controller

```
@PostMapping("/pass-to-kafka")
public void passToKafka(@RequestBody String message) {
   logger.info("This log message has trace id and span id");
   kafkaTemplate.send("my-test-topic", message);
}
```

The producer listener

```
@Bean
public ProducerListener myProducerListener() {
    return new ProducerListener<>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) { 
            logger.info("This log message is missing trace id and span id");
        }
    };
}
```

The project with the code is on GitHub: https://github.com/vaclavnemec/kafka-sleuth-problem

I expect the info message to write out trace id and span id. It should be the same values in both of the loggers.

```
INFO [bar,208706b5c40f8e93,208706b5c40f8e93,false] com.example.demo.Controller: This log message has trace id and span id
.
.
.
INFO [bar,,,] com.example.demo.DemoApplication: This log message is missing trace id and span id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set `spring.sleuth.probability=1.0` as described in the documentation and the readme. Then you'll have the tracing turned on.